# Read from SQL to textblock

Tags: c#, sql, wpf

Application — one TextBlock, one Button. + SQL database — one table.
I'm trying to read from sql to textblock, when i click the button, but it does not work.

```
private void nextButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        GetSqlData();
    }

    private void GetSqlData()
    {
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=Jama-Dharma\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=Cars;Integrated Security=True";
        SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        using (sqlConnection)
        {
            string sqlQuery = @"SELECT c.Name FROM CarsCatalog c";
            SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

            sqlConnection.Open();

            SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

            while (sqlReader.Read())
            {
                nameTextBlock.Text = sqlReader.GetString(0);
            }

            sqlConnection.Close();
        }
    }
```

How to make that when click on button, obtain the next ID values from SQL.

Comment: "Does not work" is not really an acceptable problem description - what doesn't work? What happens? What does your data look like? Edit your question to include more data about any errors you might be getting.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick glance, it looks like your while loop just overwrites the textblock.  Update the textblock text AFTER you exit the loop.  Try something like

```
 var sb = new StringBuilder();
 while (sqlReader.Read())
 {
     sb.AppendLine(sqlReader.GetString(0));
 }

 nameTextBlock.Text = sb.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save last ID you got till now, and get next ID which is greater than this saved id.
e.g:

```
    using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(...))
    {
        string sqlQuery = @"SELECT c.Name,c.ID FROM CarsCatalog c where c.ID > " 
                            + lastID.ToString();
        SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);

        sqlConnection.Open();

        SqlDataReader sqlReader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (sqlReader.Read())
        {
            nameTextBlock.Text = sqlReader.GetString(0);
            lastID = sqlReader.GetInt(1);
        }
    }
```